# How do I save a recorded video with a .3gp extension in asterisk?

Tags: h.264, asterisk, video-encoding, mpeg-4

I am working on Ubuntu.

I would like to record `on asterisk` video files with the extension .3gp inside the `voice mail` file. How can I do that?

Till now the recorded video files have been saved in the voicemail folder under the `.h263 format`, but I would like to play the files on my android phone, so I need a `.3gp or mp4 format`. How do I solve this? I need some help. I've tried using `ffmpeg` in order to convert the asterisk h263 file into an mp4 file but without success. I have input format not detected error.

Need help. Appreciate.

in sip.conf I have:

```
videosupport=yes
allow=h263
```

extensions.conf

```
exten => 1001,1,Dial(SIP/1001)
exten => 1002,2,Voicemail(1001)
exten => 1001,3,HangUp()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to know more about these .h263 files that this software produces. If you are on a Unix machine (like Mac OS X or Linux), run the 'file' command against one of the .h263 to see if the utility can automatically determine its type.